# Do command substitutions not affect the state of the shell?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

This example that stores the current directory of the script in MYDIR echos the same directory before and after the variable assignment(even though cd was called) leading me to think that command substitutions don't affect the state of the shell. Is that true for all command substitutions?

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "$PWD"
MYDIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"
echo "$PWD"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed; command substitutions are executed in a subshell. They cannot change the environment of the parent process.